# Number does not not appear in XML files in ADT editor

Tags: android, xml, eclipse-adt

I have strange problem where numbers in  XML file in my ADT not appear but appear in another editor the link below is to Image that explain what I face,  any one know why ?
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be font problem for fonts set in Eclipse try to change font to default instead of custom fonts.